# How to keep an object on top of other objects in tkinter

Tags: python, object, tkinter

I am making a game that has the main object (which the player moves) and other several objects that move around by itself that keep on spawning from the sides. I want my main object to appear on top of the other objects, but these other objects are made after my main object in my code, which means they appear on top of my main object. Is there anything I can do so that my main object always appears to be on top of every other object? Also my main object and other objects are in different classes.

Comment: I guess you are using `Canvas`, is that right?

Comment: Did this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872650/how-do-i-set-the-z-index-of-an-python-tkinter-canvas-element ?